# Submit User Inputted Numbers to be Run through a firebase function which adds the numbers and displays the result to the user

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Editing this whole post because I have done a lot of reading the last few days and modified quite a few things to reflect what I have learned, and have edited the title accordingly to make this a more coherent question

I have made a Firebase function and successfully deployed it, here it is below.

**Index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.addNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
      const firstNumber = data.firstNumber;
      const secondNumber = data.secondNumber;

      if (!Number.isFinite(firstNumber) || !Number.isFinite(secondNumber)) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'two arguments "firstNumber" and "secondNumber" which must both be numbers.');
      }

      return {
        firstNumber: firstNumber,
        secondNumber: secondNumber,
        operator: '+',
        operationResult: firstNumber + secondNumber,
      };

    });
```

This was taken almost completely from an example script from the docs but I was able to get a general understanding of how to set up the firebase functions from it. I deployed this function and it successfully showed up in my firebase console.

Where I am at right now is I have the following HTML as a set up for the calculator itself:

**app.component.html**

```
<h1 align="center">Calculator App with Firebase</h1>
<div *ngIf="result | async as resu">{{resu.operationResult}}</div>
<div>
  <form id="numbersForm">
    <label for="firstNumber">Number 1:
      <input [(ngModel)]="firstNumber" type="text"/>
    </label>
      <br><br>
    <label for="secondNumber">Number 2:
      <input [(ngModel)]="secondNumber" type="text"/>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit" (click)="onClick()">Calculate</button> <!--this is where things need to tie in together-->
```

in the `calculator.component.ts` I have imported the `AngularFire` library and have done the following:

**calculator.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';


@Component({
  selector: 'calculator',
  template: ` `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class CalculatorComponent  {
  firstNumber: Number
  secondNumber: Number

result: Observable<any>

constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) { 

    //Next Step Here That I Am Missing?
// do not setup any thing in a constructor!
  }

onClick() {
const callable = fns.httpsCallable('addNumber'); // this is some thing like init reference
this.result = callable({ firstNumber: this.firstNumber, secondNumber: this.secondNumber}) // Here you sending request and response land in this.result
}

}
```

And finally, I have created a folder in my project called `environments` with the file `environments/environment.ts` containing all of the relevant keys provided by google for me to use.

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried so far? Please also share your sample stackblitz to work with.

Comment: my mouse sort of spazzed out on me I have written the remainder of my question, also if I am not mistaken you were the one who helped me on my prior angular question

Comment: @SiddAjmera i went ahead and linked the stackblitz into the question as well

Comment: The database will store your data. But it won't do computations. You need something other than a database to implement computation on the backend.

Comment: right I will have to create a firebase function of some sort for that im guessing my main issue is getting the inputs into the database

Comment: send those  `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` to the firebase database.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda this is mostly where I am having my trouble at the moment, I tried searching elsewhere on stackOverflow and the only other question I found like this also went unanswered

Comment: exactly what you have to do? with those two input values? and to those results of two input values

Comment: @GaurangDhorda For the moment i guess im mostly concerned with getting those numbers to the database, then after this the plan is to have some firebase function which will add the two numbers together and then I will display this result back to the user.

Comment: Again; what have you tried? Here's the documentation about how to insert a document in a collection: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection. But really, you need to read all of it. https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited the question to show the most recent attempt at what I have done but I am not seeing any evidence that anything was written to a database so I scrapped it but it is now edited in above

Comment: @Banani720 If you want make some calculations out of angular application use Firebase Functions and onCall functions.

Comment: @Banani720 If you using angular 6+ use @angular/fire library it's newest version of angularfire2 library.

Comment: @JBNizet I read the docs that you have provided but still find myself a little stuck on the final steps of the process, I have edited the question almost entirely hopefully this makes it a little more valid.

Comment: @Banani720 Did you work with Observables ? Or Promises ?

Comment: @Mises observables

Comment: @Banani720 Yeah Observable<any> you know what it does ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204910/discussion-between-mises-and-banani720).

Comment: @Mises, in general, if I understand correctly observables are objects which are observed by subscribers and then the subscribers act on the observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exactly correct answer but at least a good path to make an calculations out of Angular application. Im using Angular 7+ in this example. In Angular 4+ or 6+ do not use `angularfire2` library it's an old version of `@angular/fire` library.

Firebase have a nice tool named Firebase Functions you can use them to make calculations out of your application. More about them: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/.

**index.ts example of Firebase functions**

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// This is example of how to make an simple callable function.
export const getUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return caseAdmin(data, context, getUsersList)
})
// this function will return users list if a user who call a function is an admin.
async function getUsersList() {
    try {
        const usersList = await admin.auth().listUsers()
        return usersList.users
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return { code: 'admin/get-users-list', message: "Some thing goes wrong." }
    }
}
// This function check are user have an isAdmin field in his token. To assign that kind of field to user token read about custom claims.
export function caseAdmin(data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext, callback: any){
    switch (isAuth(context)) {
        case 'isAdmin':
            return callback(data)
        case 'isEditor':
            return { code: 'admin/set-admin-error', message: 'Access denied! Only admin can add admin.' }
        case 'user':
            return { code: 'admin/set-admin-error', message: 'Access denied!' }
        case 'unknown':
            return { code: 'admin/set-admin-error', message: "Access denied!" }
        default:
            return { code: 'admin/set-admin-error', message: 'Unknown problem.' }
    }
}
// this function check are user is authenticated and what role he have.
export function isAuth(context: functions.https.CallableContext) {
    if (context && context.auth && context.auth.token.isAdmin) {
        return 'isAdmin'
    } else if (context && context.auth && context.auth.token.isEditor) {
        return 'isEditor'
    } else if (context && context.auth) {
        return 'user'
    } else {
        return 'unknown'
    }
}
```

Service in Angular application:

**admin.service.ts**

```js
export class AdminService {

  constructor(private fc: AngularFireFunctions) {
     // bellow line only for local texting so you can run functions localy
    // this.fc.functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5000') 
  }

  // Asignning what function you want to use.
  getUsersList() {
    const usersList = this.fc.httpsCallable('getUsers')
// empty object but function no need any. Context is sended automatically you can decide are user need to be authenticated or not are he have to be an admin or not. Best way to assign users role is by functions using custom claims.
    return usersList({})
  }
}
```

**Example of working really simple onCall function**

**onCall function index.ts:**

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const getUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return { message: "Hello message from onCall function"}
})
```

**component.ts**

```js
users$: Observable<any>

constructor(private fc: AngularFireFunctions) {
    // this.fc.functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5000')
  }

  onButtonClickGetUsers() {
    const usersList = this.fc.httpsCallable('getUsers')
    this.users$ = usersList({}) // here observable are making https requests to onCall functions so you get response Observable<{ message: "..."}>
  }
```

**compoonent.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="users$ | async as user"> {{ user.message }} </div>
<button (click)="onButtonClickGetUsers()">Get Users</button>
```

Comment: this answer has me close and led me most of the way there I am still a little confused on implementing this in the html and getting the result back in angular, i have edited my question accordingly

Comment: To return data to angular application just return in onCall function any object you want.

Comment: I think I did this in my firebase function I am mostly stuck on getting the return to display within the webapp itself

Comment: @Banani720 I edited an answear so i wrote a really simple onCall function.

Comment: @Banani720 You need to learn more about Firebase functions it's not an big deal by the way. XD

Comment: @Banani720 I dont know if you know what is Angular SSR or Universal. You can do it using Firebase Functions. So you can link your application in a facebook and get a nice looking cards with an picture insted of just link to page.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveInput (value1,value2){
     return this.db.collection('numbers').add({
         firstValue: value1,
         secondNumber: value2,
      });
 }  // called form calculator.component.ts
```

This will save records of numbers to collection of numbers in firebase. You have to call this method from `calculate.component` from angular.

This is you `template driven form` in angular...

```
<h1 align="center">Calculator App in Angular TypeScript</h1>
<body>
      <form id= "numbers_form" #myform = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(myform)" >
           <div id="first_number"> <!--First Number Field and Label-->
             <p>Number 1:
                <input ngModel  name = "value1" type="text">
             </p>
           </div>

           <p align='center'>  +  </p>

           <div id="second_number"> <!--Second Number Field and Label-->
                <p> Number 2:>
                     <input ngModel name = "value2" type="text">
                </p>
           </div>  
           <input type = "submit" value = "Calculate">
     </form>
        <div id="solution"> 
            <h3> Solution: </h3>
        <calculator 
            [firstNumber]="value1"
            [secondNumber]="value2">
        </calculator>
```

app.ts is...

```
value1;
value2;
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.value1 = Number(form.value['value1']);
    this.value2 = Number(form.value['value2']);
  }
```

in your calulator.component.ts..

```
firstNum;
secondNum;
@Input('firstNumber') set first(number1 : Number) {
  this.firstNum = number1;
}
@Input('secondNumber') set second  (number2: number){
  this.secondNum = number2;
}

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {}
 ngOnChanges() {
    this.saveInput(this.firstNum,this.secondNum);
  }
```

Comment: so this helped a little bit I edited the question a bit maybe the way I've laid it out will be more helpful in finding a solution?